# Database with mixed collation (utf8mb4 & utf8_general_ci)

Tags: database, mysql, table, collation

Each time I was uploading my WP install from offline to online, I was noticing strange characters in text and digging a bit I have discovered that wp-config.php on the online server was set to `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` so each time I would upload the new "release" I had to edit to wp-config.php to utf8 to display correctly extended characters.

Lately I have discovered (through phpmyadmin) not only that the default collation sequence on my install is set to utf8mb4, but also some tables in the WP db are set to utf8mb4, while others are set to utf8_general_ci...

I have read that under certain conditions WP will attempt to convert collation sequence to utf8mb4 when possible.

So now I have a fruit salad of collation sequence in my db.

What shall I do?

Comment: I have had the same issue and am currently creating a series of tests to determine what is causing the issue. I'm not sure when it started, but I have live sites now that have a mixture of collation sequences. Only when I started a recent development site with the 4.6.1 WordPress install did it start causing errors.

Comment: I think that in my case what happened was to install WP on a local computer running Wamp. All WP tables where created using utf8mb4, Then whan I have installed other plugins, utf8_general_ci was used.